# Getting OSName as a string C++

Tags: c++, windows, string, operating-system

Im am super new to C++ and am trying to figure out how to return the OSName (win 7, 8, vista, xp, etc) as a string. I tried searching and MSDN was no help, only confused me further.

All help appreciated.

Comment: Looks like it's mostly already done I guess, but not in the way you'd like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms724429(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Windows only or do you want other OSes, too? (OSX version, GNU/Linux distro version …)

Comment: Windows only, don't need any other ones

Comment: @Mike D I checked that question, the MSDN link is the one I checked but I did not understand how to use it at all.

Comment: @jorisbolsens Fair enough. You might want to update your question to show what part you don't understand.

Comment: I figured it out, I'll answer this question once I get it fully working.

Answer (score 0):

it seems using predefined headers is the easiest way

http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/

Comment: I see nothing in there that could possibly differentiate between, say, Windows 7 and XP.  Especially since that's something that would have to be determined at runtime.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley joris bolsens did not initially tell that he wants to know the Windows version … the question reads like he wants to tell different OS families apart. The comments came after thkang put his answer.

Comment: @Kay: Did he make a ninja edit? Because the question says *"OSName (win 7, 8, vista, xp, etc)"* -- and there are no apparent edits before that was there.

Answer (score -4):

What makes you think MSDN will give you the answers? Microsoft's implementation on MSDN is not standard C++, and thus you should be looking for a portable solution.

Comment: -1: `Microsoft's implementation on MSDN is not standard C++`....

Comment: @JesseGood it's clear that SevenBits meant the Windows API is not part of the C++ standard …

Comment: Exactly. You ask if there's a way to do it C++, not if it's possible to do it in Win32. In plain old C++, the answer is no without some help from the pre processor.

Comment: @kay: The MSDN website contains a lot of information (including info on there implemetation of the standard C++ library), not just the winapi. `Microsoft's implementation on MSDN` does not make any sense, MSDN is a website.

Comment: Obviously there would be no mechanism provided as part of the C++ standard to determine the version of *Windows*. The C++ language runs on lots of platforms other than Windows. This seems like a completely nonsensical argument. You'll have to call one of the Windows API functions, and they're documented on MSDN. They work fine from standard C++.

Comment: All I'm saying is he made no indication he wanted just a Windows OS. He said he wanted to do it in C++ - and MSDN is not a C++ reference, it's a Win32 reference. So looking on MSDN would not _necessarily_ have given him the answer.